# Deprecating a class constructor parameter

Tags: scala

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo(x: Int, y: Int) {}
```

I want to deprecate `x`. I tried this:

```
class Foo(@deprecated("msg", "0.1") x: Int, y: Int)
```

In Scala 2.11, I am getting the following warning:

```
[warn] /tmp/zzz/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:1:12: no valid targets for annotation on value x - it is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(deprecated("msg", "0.1") @param)
[warn] class Foo(@deprecated("msg", "0.1") x: Int, y: Int) {
[warn]            ^
[warn] one warning found
```

(I tried the suggested syntax but that would lead to a compilation error). The syntax I tried works for Scala 2.12. Is there a way to deprecate constructor parameters in a way that would work for both 2.11 and 2.12?

Comment: Like you said I have used deprecated with 2.12.X but seems to be an issue with 2.11.X - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles in 2.11 by qualifying `x` with `var` or `val`:

```
class Foo(@deprecated("msg", "0.1") var x: Int, y: Int) 
class Foo(@deprecated("msg", "0.1") val x: Int, y: Int)
```

However, as pointed out by Andrey in the comment, it does not deprecate the constructor parameter, but only the corresponding automatically generated member variables. To deprecate the constructor parameter, you cold try moving `x` to a secondary deprecated constructor:

```
class Foo(y: Int) {
  @deprecated("msg", "0.1")
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(y)
}
```

Comment: Does it deprecate a constructor parameter, or does it deprecate the corresponding automatically generated member variables? I'd assume the latter?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That is right. I've edited the answer to suggest moving `x` to a deprecated secondary constructor.